# Java constructor with and without "this" before attributes

Tags: java, constructor

Maybe this question was asked here before, but I couldn't find it here.

It is basic question for Java developers, but here it goes: lets say I have class A with attribute a. What is the difference between these 2 constructors:

```
public abstract class A
{
   protected String a;

   public A()
   {
      a = "text";
   }
}
```

The second one:

```
public abstract class A
{
   protected String a;

   public A()
   {
      this.a = "text"; //Here is the same with this
   }
}
```

Comment: There is no difference at all.

Comment: Well what it is then? Of course besides of the visual effect :)

Comment: Well, we have Skeet here. Look at the example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case you've given, there's no difference. Typically `this` is used to disambiguate between instance variables and local variables or parameters. For example:

```
public A(String a) {
    this.a = a; // Assign value from parameter to local variable
}
```

or

```
public void setFoo(int foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}
```

Some people prefer to *always* use `this.variableName` to make it clearer to anyone reading the code; personally I find that if the class is well designed and the methods are short enough, it's usually clear enough already and the extra qualification just adds cruft. YMMV.

Comment: From what I found, if there is some other class B which uses class A with the first constructor like this: `A a = new A();` then a's attributes are `null`. I can post more complex example. after adding `this` before the attributes (like in the second constructor) the attributes was filled with data (in the example case "text").

Comment: @Vlad: no, that won't be the case unless you've got a parameter or local variable called within the constructor.

Comment: there are a local parameters. 2 local and 2 class parameters.`respJson   = new JSONObject(resp);
   this.data  = respJson.getJSONObject(DATA);
   this.errors  = respJson.getJSONObject(ERRORS);
   response  = respJson.getString(RESPONSE);`

Comment: @Vlad: I suggest you ask a new question with a short but complete example demonstrating the problem. Comments aren't really appropriate for this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in your specific case. But let's think about a constructor with an argument which has the same name as an attribute:

```
public abstract class A {
   protected String a;

   public A(String a) {
      this.a = a; 
   }
}
```

In that specific case, `this.a` is referring to the `a` attribute of class `A`, while `a` is referring to the local parameter

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference at all, unless there is shadowing involved:

```
public abstract class A
{
   protected String a;

   public A(String a)
   {
      this.a = a; // assign external one to inner
   }
}
```

vs

```
public abstract class A
{
   protected String a;

   public A(String a)
   {
      a = a; // assign inner one to inner one
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) and with your same example ,

> The most common reason for using the this keyword is because a field is shadowed by a method or constructor parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the constructor `this` reference is used to automatically pass address of the caller object.